# Where does named pipe (FIFO) data go when reader disconnects?

Tags: unix, go, fifo, mkfifo

Let's say I have a `producer.go` and `consumer.go`.  The `consumer.go` reads from a UNIX named pipe, and the producer writes to the named pipe.

As expected, If you start up **just one** of the producer or consumer programs, it hangs because there's no reader or writer on the other side of the pipe.

Now, If I start both programs, then immediately CTRL-C from the consumer, the producer continues sending data to the pipe and as far as I can tell there's no limit to the size of that data (I've sent 80MB)

If I start the consumer program again (while the producer is still running), it starts pulling data off of the named pipe, but not the data that I "missed" while the consumer program was not running.

My question is: **When a reader of a named pipe disconnects, what happens to the data that's sent to the named pipe?**

Here are my `consumer.go` and `producer.go` programs:

consumer.go

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    syscall.Mkfifo("fifo0", 0777)
    fp, err := os.OpenFile("fifo0", os.O_RDONLY, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not open fifo0: %s", err)
    }
    tee := io.TeeReader(fp, os.Stdout)
    ioutil.ReadAll(tee)
}
```

producer.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    dots := strings.Repeat(".", 990)
    fifo, err := os.OpenFile("fifo0", os.O_WRONLY, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not open fifo0: %s", err)
    }
    defer fifo.Close()
    w := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, fifo)
    for i := 0; i < 8000; i++ {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%010d%s\n", i, dots)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the errors from writing to the pipe

Comment: When I check for errors, it appears that it does show an error when there's no receiver but it doesn't block, that's nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

A FIFO requires at least one source and one destination for data to get transferred anywhere. A reader alone waits to pull from someone, and a writer alone waits to send to someone. In this way, there are no gaps in a one-to-one pipe.

So if you're still trying to read or write from one end of a disconnected or nonexistent pipe, the answer is that **the data is going nowhere**; the pipe is "blocked" and can hold no data of its own. So it depends on how your code handles this situation.

In `producer.go`, the loop continues to run even when there's no longer a connection. Because `Fprintf` or `MultiWriter` don't raise a code-stopping error for whatever reason. In this case you could either add a check in the loop or an event handler for the `fifo` object's disconnection.

The reason it seems that there's a gap of disappearing data, is because the loop continues to iterate for `i` and generate strings it can't send.